# Curious identity between the two kinds of Chebyshev polynomials

Tags: polynomials, combinatorial-identities, trigonometric-polynomials

I have found, by accident, an identity that relates a sum of Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind to a Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind. It goes as follows:

Given an integer partition of $n$, let $g_a$ be the number of times $a$ appears in said partition.${}^1$ Then the following identity holds for all $n \in\mathbb{N}$:

$$
U_n(x) = \sum_{\substack{n_i>0\\ \sum_i n_i = n}} \frac{1}{\prod_{a\in \{n_i\}} g_a!} \prod_{i=1} \frac{2}{n_i} T_{n_i}(x)\,.
$$

The sum is over all integer partitions of $n$, the product is on all $n_i$'s in the partition, with repetitions.

I have a very roundabout way to prove this identity (I'll skip the details). The left hand side is obtained by contracting two symmetric traceless tensors of $SO(4)$. That is, letting $|x|=|y|=1$ and $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^4$ then
$$
(x^{i_1}\cdots x^{i_n} - \mathrm{traces}) (y_{i_1}\cdots y_{i_n} - \mathrm{traces}) \propto U_n(x\cdot y)\,.
$$
The right hand side instead comes from the same contraction but in spinor notation. Namely we let
$$
\mathrm{x} = \left(\begin{matrix}x_3-x_4 & x_1 - i x_2 \\ x_1 + i x_2 & -x_3-x_4\end{matrix}\right)\,,\quad \bar{\mathrm{x}} = \epsilon\, \mathrm{x}\, \epsilon^T\,,
$$
and $\mathrm{y}$ in a similar way ($\epsilon$ is the Levi Civita tensor). Then we introduce two dimensional spinors $\eta,\tilde{\eta}$ let $\partial_{\eta^\alpha}\eta^\beta = \delta_\alpha^\beta$ (similar for $\tilde{\eta}$) and finally
$$
(\partial_\eta \mathrm{x} \partial_{\tilde{\eta}})^n (\eta \mathrm{y}\tilde{\eta})^n \sim  \sum_{\substack{n_i>0\\ \sum_i n_i = n}} \# \prod_{i} \mathrm{tr}\,((\mathrm{x}\bar{\mathrm{y}})^{n_i})\,.
$$
The sum over partitions comes from a combinatoric argument. Then it's a simple exercise to show that $\mathrm{tr}\,((\mathrm{x}\bar{\mathrm{y}})^n) \propto T_n(x\cdot y)$.

My questions are

1. Is this identity known already?
2. If not, could you come up with some more direct argument to prove it?

---

$\;{}^1$ For example, $(1,1,1,2,2,3)$ is an integer partition of $n=10$ with $g_1 =3,\, g_2=2,\,g_3=1$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how to prove it with more standard methods. First of all, let me
restate your identity:

> **Definition.** Let $\mathbb{N}=\left\{  0,1,2,\ldots\right\}  $. A
>   *partition* shall mean [an integer
>   partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)), i.e., a
>   weakly decreasing finite list of positive integers. If $\lambda$ is a partition
>   and $i$ is a positive integer, then $m_{i}\left(  \lambda\right)  $ shall mean
>   the number of times that $i$ appears as entry of $\lambda$. (For example,
>   $m_{3}\left(  \left(  4,3,3,1\right)  \right)  =2$ and $m_{2}\left(  \left(
> 4,3,3,1\right)  \right)  =0$.) The *size* $\left\vert \lambda\right\vert $ of
>   a partition is defined to be the sum of all entries of $\lambda$. If
>   $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then a *partition of $n$* means a partition of size $n$. We
>   write "$\lambda\vdash n$" for "$\lambda$ is a partition of $n$".
>
> **Definition.** We let $T_n\left(x\right)$ denote [the Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials), which can be defined (e.g.) by the recurrence $T_0\left(x\right) = 1$ and $T_1\left(x\right) = x$ and $T_{n+1}\left(x\right) = 2x T_n\left(x\right) - T_{n-1}\left(x\right)$. We let $U_n\left(x\right)$ denote [the Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials), which can be defined (e.g.) by the recurrence $U_0\left(x\right) = 1$ and $U_1\left(x\right) = 2x$ and $U_{n+1}\left(x\right) = 2x U_n\left(x\right) - U_{n-1}\left(x\right)$.
>
> **Theorem 1.** For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have
>   \begin{equation}
> U_{n}\left(  x\right)  =\sum_{\lambda=\left(  \lambda_{1},\lambda_{2}
> ,\ldots,\lambda_{k}\right)  \vdash n}\left(  \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\dfrac
> {1}{i^{m_{i}\left(  \lambda\right)  }m_{i}\left(  \lambda\right)  !}\right)
> \cdot\prod_{j=1}^{k}\left(  2T_{\lambda_{j}}\left(  x\right)  \right)  .
> \end{equation}

To prove this, I will use two well-known generating-function identities for
Chebyshev polynomials, both of which appear on [the
Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Definition):
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}T_{n}\left(  x\right)  t^{n}=\dfrac{1-tx}{1-2tx+t^{2}}
\label{darij1.eq.T-gen}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}U_{n}\left(  x\right)  t^{n}=\dfrac{1}{1-2tx+t^{2}
}.
\label{darij1.eq.U-gen}
\tag{2}
\end{equation}
These are identities in the ring $\left(  \mathbb{Q}\left[  x\right]  \right)
\left[  \left[  t\right]  \right]  $ of formal power series in the variable
$t$ over the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Q}\left[  x\right]  $. Both identities can easily be derived from the above recurrent definitions of $T_n\left(x\right)$ and $U_n\left(x\right)$.

Now, subtracting the equality $\underbrace{T_{0}\left(  x\right)  }
_{=1}\underbrace{t^{0}}_{=1}=1$ from the identity \eqref{darij1.eq.T-gen}, we obtain
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}T_{n}\left(  x\right)  t^{n}=\dfrac{1-tx}{1-2tx+t^{2}
}-1=t\cdot\dfrac{x-t}{1-2tx+t^{2}}.
\end{equation}
Dividing both sides of this by $t$, we obtain
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}T_{n}\left(  x\right)  t^{n-1} = \dfrac{x-t}{1-2tx+t^{2}}.
\end{equation}
Integrating both sides of this equality over $t$, we find
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}T_{n}\left(  x\right)  \dfrac{t^{n}}{n}  & =\int\dfrac
{x-t}{1-2tx+t^{2}}dt\nonumber\\
& =\dfrac{1}{2}\log\dfrac{1}{1-2tx+t^{2}}
\label{darij1.eq.T-ge2}
\tag{3}
\end{align}
(as you can easily check by differentiation). (Note that this identity also
appears on the Wikipedia, under the guise of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}T_{n}\left(
x\right)  \dfrac{t^{n}}{n}=\log\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-2tx+t^{2}}}$, apparently
because someone finds square roots simpler than division by $2$.)

Multiplying both sides of the equality \eqref{darij1.eq.T-ge2}
by $2$, we obtain
\begin{equation}
2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}T_{n}\left(  x\right)  \dfrac{t^{n}}{n}=\log\dfrac
{1}{1-2tx+t^{2}}.
\end{equation}
Hence,
\begin{equation}
\log\dfrac{1}{1-2tx+t^{2}}=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}T_{n}\left(  x\right)
\dfrac{t^{n}}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2T_{n}\left(  x\right)  \dfrac{t^{n}}{n},
\end{equation}
so that
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{1}{1-2tx+t^{2}}=\exp\left(  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2T_{n}\left(  x\right)
\dfrac{t^{n}}{n}\right)  .
\end{equation}
Hence, \eqref{darij1.eq.U-gen} becomes
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}U_{n}\left(  x\right)  t^{n}=\dfrac{1}{1-2tx+t^{2}}
=\exp\left(  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2T_{n}\left(  x\right)  \dfrac{t^{n}}
{n}\right)  .
\label{darij1.eq.T-ge3}
\tag{4}
\end{equation}

Now, we recall one of the staple formulas of algebraic combinatorics (probably
in EC or Wilf or similar sources):

> **Proposition 2.** Let $R$ be a commutative $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra (for example,
>   $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Q}\left[  x\right]  $). Let $b_{1},b_{2},b_{3}
> ,\ldots\in R$ and $c_{0},c_{1},c_{2},\ldots\in R$ be such that
>   \begin{equation}
> \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}t^{n}=\exp\left(  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}\dfrac
> {t^{n}}{n}\right)
> \end{equation}
>   in the ring $R\left[  \left[  t\right]  \right]  $ of formal power series.
>   Then,
>   \begin{equation}
> c_{n}=\sum_{\lambda=\left(  \lambda_{1},\lambda_{2},\ldots,\lambda_{k}\right)
> \vdash n}\left(  \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{i^{m_{i}\left(  \lambda\right)
> }m_{i}\left(  \lambda\right)  !}\right)  \cdot\prod_{j=1}^{k}b_{\lambda_{j}}
> \end{equation}
>   for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

*Proof of Proposition 2.* An infinite sequence $\left(  k_{1},k_{2}
,k_{3},\ldots\right)  \in\mathbb{N}^{\infty}$ of nonnegative integers will be
called a *weak composition* if all but finitely many $i\geq1$ satisfy
$k_{i}=0$. There is a bijection
\begin{align}
\left\{  \text{partitions}\right\}    & \rightarrow\left\{  \text{weak
compositions}\right\}  ,\nonumber\\
\lambda & \mapsto\left(  m_{1}\left(  \lambda\right)  ,m_{2}\left(
\lambda\right)  ,m_{3}\left(  \lambda\right)  ,\ldots\right)
\label{darij1.pf.p2.1}
\tag{5}
\end{align}
(since any partition $\lambda$ is uniquely determined by the numbers
$m_{1}\left(  \lambda\right)  ,m_{2}\left(  \lambda\right)  ,m_{3}\left(
\lambda\right)  ,\ldots$ which record how often each positive integer appears
in $\lambda$). We notice that any partition $\lambda$ satisfies
\begin{equation}
1m_{1}\left(  \lambda\right)  +2m_{2}\left(  \lambda\right)  +3m_{3}\left(
\lambda\right)  +\cdots=\left\vert \lambda\right\vert
\label{darij1.pf.p2.2}
\tag{6}
\end{equation}
(because $\left\vert \lambda\right\vert $ is the sum of all entries of
$\lambda$, while $1m_{1}\left(  \lambda\right)  +2m_{2}\left(  \lambda\right)
+3m_{3}\left(  \lambda\right)  +\cdots$ is what becomes of this sum after
equal addends are bunched together). Moreover, any partition $\lambda=\left(
\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2},\ldots,\lambda_{k}\right)  $ satisfies
\begin{equation}
\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}b_{i}^{m_{i}\left(  \lambda\right)  }=\prod_{j=1}
^{k}b_{\lambda_{j}}
\label{darij1.pf.p2.3}
\tag{7}
\end{equation}
(for a similar reason: the product $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}b_{i}^{m_{i}\left(
\lambda\right)  }$ is what will become of the product $\prod_{j=1}
^{k}b_{\lambda_{j}}$ if you bunch factors corresponding to equal entries of
$\lambda$ together).

We have the following product rule (i.e., analogue of the distributivity law)
for infinite products of infinite sums: If $\left(  a_{i,k}\right)
_{i\geq1\text{ and }k\geq0}$ is a family of elements of $R\left[  \left[
t\right]  \right]  $ satisfying $a_{i,0}=1$ for each $i\geq1$, then
\begin{equation}
\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{i,k}=\sum_{\substack{\left(
k_{1},k_{2},k_{3},\ldots\right)  \text{ is a}\\\text{weak composition}}
}\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{i,k_{i}},
\label{darij1.pf.p2.prodrule}
\tag{8}
\end{equation}
provided that everything formally converges (i.e., for each given
$N\in\mathbb{N}$, all but finitely many pairs $\left(  i,k\right)  \in\left\{
1,2,3,\ldots\right\}  ^{2}$ satisfy
$t^N \mid a_{i,k}$ in $R\left[\left[t\right]\right]$).

We have
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}t^{n}  & =\exp\left(  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}
\dfrac{t^{n}}{n}\right)  =\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\underbrace{\exp\left(
b_{n}\dfrac{t^{n}}{n}\right)  }_{\substack{=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}
{k!}\left(  b_{n}\dfrac{t^{n}}{n}\right)  ^{k}\\\text{(since }\exp
z=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{k!}z^{k}\text{)}}}\nonumber\\
& \qquad \left(\text{since $\exp\left(\sum_{i\in I} a_i\right) = \prod_{i\in I} \exp a_i$ for any family $\left(a_i\right)_{i\in I}$}\right)
\nonumber\\
& =\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{k!}\left(  b_{n}
\dfrac{t^{n}}{n}\right)  ^{k}=\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac
{1}{k!}\underbrace{\left(  b_{i}\dfrac{t^{i}}{i}\right)  ^{k}}_{=\dfrac
{b_{i}^{k}t^{ik}}{i^{k}}}\nonumber\\
& \qquad\left(  \text{here, we have renamed the index }n\text{ as }i\right)
\nonumber\\
& =\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{k!}\cdot\dfrac{b_{i}
^{k}t^{ik}}{i^{k}}=\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{b_{i}
^{k}t^{ik}}{i^{k}k!}\nonumber\\
& =\sum_{\substack{\left(  k_{1},k_{2},k_{3},\ldots\right)  \text{ is
a}\\\text{weak composition}}}\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{b_{i}^{k_{i}}
t^{ik_{i}}}{i^{k_{i}}k_{i}!}\nonumber\\
& \qquad\left(  \text{by the product rule \eqref{darij1.pf.p2.prodrule},
applied to }a_{i,k}=\dfrac{b_{i}^{k}t^{ik}}{i^{k}k!}\right)  \nonumber\\
& =\sum_{\lambda\text{ is a partition}}\underbrace{\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}
\dfrac{b_{i}^{m_{i}\left(  \lambda\right)  }t^{im_{i}\left(  \lambda\right)
}}{i^{m_{i}\left(  \lambda\right)  }m_{i}\left(  \lambda\right)  !}}_{=\left(
\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{i^{m_{i}\left(  \lambda\right)  }m_{i}\left(
\lambda\right)  !}\right)  \left(  \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}b_{i}^{m_{i}\left(
\lambda\right)  }\right)  \left(  \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}t^{im_{i}\left(
\lambda\right)  }\right)  }\nonumber\\
& \qquad\left(
\begin{array}
[c]{c}
\text{here, we have substituted }\left(  m_{1}\left(  \lambda\right)
,m_{2}\left(  \lambda\right)  ,m_{3}\left(  \lambda\right)  ,\ldots\right)  \\
\text{for }\left(  k_{1},k_{2},k_{3},\ldots\right)  \text{ in the sum, due to
the bijection \eqref{darij1.pf.p2.1}}
\end{array}
\right)  \nonumber\\
& =\sum_{\lambda\text{ is a partition}}\left(  \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\dfrac
{1}{i^{m_{i}\left(  \lambda\right)  }m_{i}\left(  \lambda\right)  !}\right)
\left(  \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}b_{i}^{m_{i}\left(  \lambda\right)  }\right)
\underbrace{\left(  \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}t^{im_{i}\left(  \lambda\right)
}\right)  }_{\substack{=t^{1m_{1}\left(  \lambda\right)  +2m_{2}\left(
\lambda\right)  +3m_{3}\left(  \lambda\right)  +\cdots}\\=t^{\left\vert
\lambda\right\vert }\\\text{(by \eqref{darij1.pf.p2.2})}}}\nonumber\\
& =\sum_{\lambda\text{ is a partition}}\left(  \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\dfrac
{1}{i^{m_{i}\left(  \lambda\right)  }m_{i}\left(  \lambda\right)  !}\right)
\left(  \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}b_{i}^{m_{i}\left(  \lambda\right)  }\right)
t^{\left\vert \lambda\right\vert }.
\label{darij1.pf.p2.6}
\tag{9}
\end{align}

Now, let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Comparing coefficients of $t^{n}$ on both sides of
the equality \eqref{darij1.pf.p2.6}, we obtain
\begin{align*}
c_{n}  & =\underbrace{\sum_{\substack{\lambda\text{ is a partition;}
\\\left\vert \lambda\right\vert =n}}}_{\substack{=\sum_{\lambda\vdash
n}\\\text{(since the partitions of }n\\\text{are precisely the partitions
}\lambda\\\text{with }\left\vert \lambda\right\vert =n\text{)}}}\left(
\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{i^{m_{i}\left(  \lambda\right)  }m_{i}\left(
\lambda\right)  !}\right)  \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}b_{i}^{m_{i}\left(
\lambda\right)  }\\
& =\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}\left(  \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{i^{m_{i}\left(
\lambda\right)  }m_{i}\left(  \lambda\right)  !}\right)  \prod_{i=1}^{\infty
}b_{i}^{m_{i}\left(  \lambda\right)  }\\
& =\sum_{\lambda=\left(  \lambda_{1},\lambda_{2},\ldots,\lambda_{k}\right)
\vdash n}\left(  \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{i^{m_{i}\left(  \lambda\right)
}m_{i}\left(  \lambda\right)  !}\right)  \underbrace{\left(  \prod
_{i=1}^{\infty}b_{i}^{m_{i}\left(  \lambda\right)  }\right)  }
_{\substack{=\prod_{j=1}^{k}b_{\lambda_{j}}\\\text{(by
\eqref{darij1.pf.p2.3})}}}\\
& =\sum_{\lambda=\left(  \lambda_{1},\lambda_{2},\ldots,\lambda_{k}\right)
\vdash n}\left(  \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{i^{m_{i}\left(  \lambda\right)
}m_{i}\left(  \lambda\right)  !}\right)  \prod_{j=1}^{k}b_{\lambda_{j}}.
\end{align*}
This proves Proposition 2. $\blacksquare$

*Proof of Theorem 1.* Recall the identity \eqref{darij1.eq.T-ge3}. Thus,
Proposition 2 (applied to $R=\mathbb{Q}\left[  x\right]  $ and $c_{n}
=U_{n}\left(  x\right)  $ and $b_{n}=2T_{n}\left(  x\right)  $) yields that
\begin{equation}
U_{n}\left(  x\right)  =\sum_{\lambda=\left(  \lambda_{1},\lambda_{2}
,\ldots,\lambda_{k}\right)  \vdash n}\left(  \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\dfrac
{1}{i^{m_{i}\left(  \lambda\right)  }m_{i}\left(  \lambda\right)  !}\right)
\cdot\prod_{j=1}^{k}\left(  2T_{\lambda_{j}}\left(  x\right)  \right)
\end{equation}
for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. This proves Theorem 1. $\blacksquare$

Comment: After your proof I realized that this could be trivially generalized to general Gegenbauer polynomials by letting $U_n(x)\to G_n^{(\alpha)}(x)$ and $2T_{\lambda_j}(x) \to 2\alpha T_{\lambda_j}(x) $. Furthermore, for $\alpha = (d-2)/2$, $d\in\mathbb{N}$ I can prove it in my way too.

Comment: Why only for the canonical scaling dimension $\alpha$? There is no reason to be afraid of fractional free fields.

Comment: I was about to show the details of my proof in a self-answer but I did not have time today. Essentially I want to express the left hand side as a contraction of $d$ dimensional, rank $n$ symmetric traceless tensors and the right hand side as traces of products of matrices belonging to the Clifford algebra in $d$ dimensions. While I believe these concepts can be generalized to any $d$, I have no rigorous way of doing so.

Answer (score 6):

I think I can sketch a shorter proof.

Let $z_j = x_j+x_j^{-1}$, and let $p_m$ and $h_m$ denote the power-sum and complete homogeneous symmetric polynomial.

Then (see e.g p.3 in [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.12725.pdf))
$$
2 T_m(z_j/2) = p_m(x_j,x_j^{-1})
\text{ and }
U_m(z_j/2) = h_m(x_j,x_j^{-1})
$$

Now, we can use the [Newton identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Expressing_complete_homogeneous_symmetric_polynomials_in_terms_of_power_sums), to express $h_m$
in terms of the power-sum symmetric functions.
This gives a relation between the $U_m$ and the $T_m$.

Looking at your formula, it is very similar to the Newton identity.

Comment: +1. I agree this is probably the best way to understand the identity. Another relevant reference is the article "Miraculous cancellations for quantum SL2" by Francis Bonahon, https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.07617

Comment: Ah -- I actually got my proof by reverse engineering a symmetric functions argument, but I wasn't aware of you proving the necessary formulas in your preprint!